# Android imagebutton with changable image

Tags: android, selection, imagebutton

Trying to make a timetabling app on android for Autistic children, but have hit a stumbling block with ImageButton. What I want to do is have the button move to a second screen when clicked, show the user a choice of images, and then whatever they click is set to the ImageButton.

I've tried implementing it by adding an ID to the buttons image and then using a selector to update the image accordingly but this seems ineffective. Any help with this would be appreciated even if just a point in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You Could just open a Dialog when you click the button. and then set the image with a function like this:

```
NAMEOFYOURBUTTON.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOURIMAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use simple BUTTON and on select of specific image set it to background of your button

you can also handle it with implementing customView class...